# Why can't I access methods specific to my child class?

Tags: c#, object, polymorphism

In C#, I have a parent class with a public member. I want to derive the parent class, then derive the class of the public member, so as to create and access new methods, as follows...

```
    public class Animal { }
    public class Sheep : Animal {
        public void makeALamb() { }
    }
    public class Farm
    {
        public Animal myAnimal;
    }
    public class SheepFarm : Farm {
        public void SheepFarm() {
            this.myAnimal = new Sheep();
            this.myAnimal.makeALamb();
        }
    }
```

This code doesn't compile. "Animal does not contain a definition for makeALamb()". But what I want to do is the essence of polymorphism, no? What am I missing? I'm greatly looking forward to finding out.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm guessing correctly what you're intending to do, consider using generics:

```
public class Farm<TAnimal> where TAnimal : Animal
{
    public TAnimal myAnimal;
}

public class SheepFarm : Farm<Sheep>
{
    public void SheepFarm()
    {
        this.myAnimal = new Sheep();
        this.myAnimal.makeALamb();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Because `myAnimal` is of type `Animal`. As such, it can only access members of `Animal`... and `Animal` doesn't have a method `makeALamb`.

The right hand side of the assignment here:

```
this.myAnimal = new Sheep();
```

..says what it is. The left hand side says what your code sees it as. The left hand side in your assignment is:

```
public Animal myAnimal;
//     ^^^^^^
```

Now.. pretend that what you've tried is possible.. consider this:

```
this.myAnimal = new Snake();
this.myAnimal.makeALamb(); // what does it call here?

this.myAnimal = new Giraffe();
this.myAnimal.makeALamb(); // what here?
```

..what should happen when you call `makeALamb` on a `Snake` instance? ...

Answer (score 0):

`makeALamb()` is a method of `Sheep`, not `Animal`. `Sheep` derives from `Animal`, not the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

`this.myAnimal` is *defined* as an `Animal`.  `Animal` does not have a `makeALamb` method.  Since you *put* a `Sheep` in `this.myAnimal`, you *could* cast it:

```
((Sheep)this.myAnimal).makeALamb();
```

This effectively says:  "Take `this.myAnimal`, treat is as a `Sheep` and call `makeALamb()` on it".  If `this.myAnimal` is not *really* a Sheep at run-time, you'll get an exception.

Answer (score 0):

You have to cast your `Animal` instance to `Sheep` if you want to access  `makeALamb` method.

```
public void SheepFarm() 
{
    this.myAnimal = new Sheep();
    ((Sheep)this.myAnimal).makeALamb();
}
```

Without a cast `myAnimal` is considered as type of `Animal` and therefore you can only access the members of `Animal` and the members of base class(es) of `Animal` (which there is no base class olf `Animal` in this case).

On the other hand, ofcourse this is not an elegant and secure way to access a class member.If you want to access some common members via a base class instance, then you should declare that members in your base class (maybe as *abstract* or *virtual*), and then implement (or override) them in derived classes.

Comment: Yes but that kinda defeats the purpose .. downcasting just to access things.. ickypants.

Comment: I would probably show the OP how to cast safely with `as`.. given that you've now opened a can of worms for the OP to just randomly start downcasting to derived classes.. and it may not succeed :(

Answer (score 0):

The idea is that your Animal can be instantiated as Sheep, but it will handle only the members defined on Animal. It is as simple as: Sheep is an Animal, but Animal is not a Sheep, so the Animal can not makeALamb() :)

Answer (score 0):

you have not defined the Farm class well. Here is example:

```
 public class Animal { }
    public class Sheep : Animal {
        public void makeALamb() { }
    }
public class Goat: Animal {
        public void makeAGoat() { }
    }
    public class Farm
    {
        public Goat myGoat;
        public Sheep mySheep;
    }
    public class MyFarm : Farm {
        public void MyFarm() {
            this.mySheep= new Animal();
            this.mySheep.makeALamb();
        }
    }
```

Every animal is not goat but every goat is an animal.

Answer (score 0):

Since, you want to use polymorphism, change your code to:

```
public abstract class Animal 
{
    public abstract void makeChild();
}

public class Sheep : Animal
{
    public override void makeChild() 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("A lamb is born.");
    }
}

public class Cow : Animal
{
    public override void makeChild()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("A calf is born.");
    }
}

public class Farm
{
    public Animal myAnimal;
}

public class SheepFarm : Farm
{
    public SheepFarm()
    {
        this.myAnimal = new Sheep();
        this.myAnimal.makeChild();
    }
}

public class CowFarm : Farm
{
    public CowFarm()
    {
        this.myAnimal = new Cow();
        this.myAnimal.makeChild();
    }
}
```

and, use the following "Main()" method:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Farm sf = new SheepFarm();
        Farm cf = new CowFarm();
    }
}
```

However, I should point to you that this is not a good use case scenario. A better and simpler use case of polymorphism would be to get rid of the Farm classes and use the following "Main()" method instead of the previous one:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Animal[] animals = {
            new Sheep(),
            new Cow(),
            new Sheep(),
            new Cow(),
            new Cow()
        };

        foreach (Animal animal in animals)
        {
            animal.makeChild();
        }
    }
}
```